# Reduce subsequence problem complexity from exponential to polynomial?

Tags: c++, memoization, subset-sum

I am working on [the following problem](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/subset-with-sum-divisible-by-m/0):

> Given a set of non-negative distinct integers, and a value m, determine if there is a subset of the given set with sum divisible by m.
>
> **Input:** The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. Then T test cases follow. The first line of each test case contains an integer N and M where N denotes the size of the array and M is the number for which we have to check the divisibility.  The second line of each test case contains N space separated integers denoting elements of the array A[ ].
>
> **Output:** If there is a subset which is divisible by M print '1' else print '0'.

I have tried a recursive solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
using namespace std;

bool find_it(int a[],int &m,int n,int sum) {
    if ((sum%m)==0 && sum>0)
        return true;
    if (n==0)
        return false;
    return find_it(a,m,n-1,sum) || find_it(a,m,n-1,sum-a[n-1]);
}

int main() {
    int tc;
    cin >> tc;
    while (tc--) {
        int n,m;
        cin >> n >> m;
        int a[n];
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            cin >> a[i];
            sum += a[i];
        }
        bool answer = find_it(a,m,n,sum);
        cout << answer << "\n";
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Which works fine and get accepted, but then I tried top-down approach, and am getting TLE ("Time Limit Exceeded").  What am I doing wrong in this memoization?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
using namespace std;

bool find_it(
    int a[], int &m, int n, int sum,
    unordered_map<int,unordered_map<int,bool>> &value,
    unordered_map<int,unordered_map<int,bool>> &visited){

    if ((sum%m)==0 && sum>0)
        return true;
    if(n==0)
        return false;

    if(visited[n][sum]==true)
        return value[n][sum];

    bool first = false,second = false;
    first = find_it(a,m,n-1,su1m,value,visited);

    if(sum<a[n-1])
    {
        second=false;
    }
    else
    second = find_it(a,m,n-1,sum-a[n-1],value,visited);

    visited[n][sum] = true;
    value[n][sum] = first || second;
    return value[n][sum];
}

int main() {
    int tc;
    cin >> tc;
    while (tc--) {
        int n,m;
        cin >> n >> m;
        int a[n];
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            cin >> a[i];
            sum+=a[i];
        }
        unordered_map<int,unordered_map<int,bool>> value;
        unordered_map<int,unordered_map<int,bool>> visited;
        cout << find_it(a,m,n,sum,value,visited) << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` should not be used. ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)) `using namespace std;` should be avoided, especially at global scope. ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)). Together they emphasize each other's worst aspect and can lead to some truly bizarre errors.

Comment: Hint: There's a solution in O(m*n).

Comment: @aschepler, I guess you are talking about geeksforgeeks article on this problem .Thanks, but I am trying to know why the recursive code works but memoized code doesn't work(giving TLE).(learning dynamic programming right now).link-https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/subset-with-sum-divisible-by-m/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at first, you can reduce the problem to a *modulo `m`* problem, as properties of integers don't change when switching to *modulo `m`* field.  It's easy to demonstrate that being divisible by `m` is the same as being identical to `0` *mod `m`*.

I would first convert all those numbers to their counterparts *modulo `m`* and eliminate repetitions by considering `a_i`, `2*a_i`, `3*a_i`,... until `rep_a_i * a_i`, all of them *mod `m`*.  Finally you get a reduced set that has at most `m` elements.  Then eliminate all the zeros there, as they don't contribute to the sum.  This is important for two reasons:

- It converts your problem from a Knapsack problem (**NP-complete**) on which complexity is `O(a^n)` into a `O(K)` problem, as its complexity doesn't depend on the number of elements of the set, but the number `m`.
- You can still have a large set of numbers to compute.  You can consider the reduced set a Knapsack problem and try to check (and further reduce it) for an easy-knapsack problem (the one in which the different values `a_i` follow a geometric sequence with `K > 2`)

The rest of the problem is a [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) (which is **NP-complete**) or one of it's **P** variants.

In case you don't get so far (cannot reduce it to an easy-knapsack problem) then you have to reduce the number of `a_i`'s so the exponential time gets a minimum exponent :)

## edit

(@mss asks for elaboration in a comment) Assume you have `m = 8`  and the list is `1 2 4 6 12 14 22`.  After reduction *mod `m`* the list remains as: `1 2 4 6 4 6 6` in which 6 is repeated three times.  we must consider the three possible repetitions of 6, as they can contribute to get a sum, but not more (for the moment), let's consider `6*1 = 6`, `6*2 = 12` and `6*3 = 18`, the first is the original `6`, the second makes a third repetition of `4` (so we'll need to consider 3 `4`s in the list), and the third converts into a `2`.  So now, we have `1 2 4 6 4 4 2` in the list.  We make the same for the `4` repetitions (two `4` run into `8` which is `0`*mod `m`* and don't contribute to sums, but we have to keep one such `0` because this means you got by repeated numbers the target `m`) getting into `1 2 4 6 0 4 2` => `1 2 4 6 0 0 2` =(reorder)=> `0 1 2 2 4 6` => `0 1 2 4 6`.  This should be the final list to consider.  As it has a `0`, you know *a priori* that there's one such sum (in this case you got is as including the two `4`, for the original list's `4` and `12` numbers.

Comment: can you please elaborate your second paragraph more through bit of hint code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `value`.  Once you find a valid combination, i.e. if `find_it` ever returns `true`, you can just immediately return true in all recursive calls.

Some additional remarks:

1. You should use consistent indentation.
2. Variable sized arrays as in `int a[n]` are not standard C++ and will not work on all compilers.
3. There is no reason to pass `m` as `int&` instead of `int`.
4. A `map` taking boolean values is the same as a `set` where the element is assumed to map to `true` if it is in the set and `false` if it is not. Consider using `unordered_set` instead of `unordered_map`.
5. Composing two `unordered_map`s like this is expensive. You can just as easily put both keys into a `std::pair` and use that as key. This would avoid the overhead of maintaining the map.
6. `bits/stdc++.h` is also non-standard and you should specify the correct header files instead, e.g. `#include <unordered_map>` and `#include <iostream>`.
7. You should put spaces between the variable type and its name, even if the `>` from the template parameter allows it to parse correctly without. It makes code hard to read.